# Remove Etag and Last-Modified headers with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Running a Vue app that deploys to Firebase hosting. The solution works well, but it's unnecessary for us to serve `Etag` and `Last-Modified` for our dynamically generated files (using web pack).

Our cache policy benefits the most from not having the header-roundtrip to the server for a lot of our files.

This is the part where we set the cache headers, but I can only add, and not remove headers.

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "/**",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "source": "**/*.@(ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=31536000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is there any way with Firebase hosting to remove `Etag` and `Last-modified` for the items with heavy cache?